# With what values Array2DRowRealMatrix get initialised when declared?

Tags: java, logistic-regression, knime

I am trying to figure out Logistic Regression implemented in Knime tool. Pls see https://github.com/knime/knime-core/blob/master/org.knime.base/src/org/knime/base/node/mine/regression/logistic/learner3/Learner.java

In the irlsRls method, there are many Array2DRowRealMatrix used like

```
    RealMatrix x = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(1, rC + 1);
    RealMatrix eBetaTx = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(1, tcC - 1);
    RealMatrix pi = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(1, tcC - 1);
```

I have gone through the documentation for RealMatrix and understood the arguments say the row and column dimension. But can someone say with what values it is initialised when declared as I see lot of usage of these declared variables before assigning any values to it. Any help appreciated. Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It takes the Number of rows and columns in the new matrix

```
public Array2DRowRealMatrix(int rowDimension,
                int columnDimension)
                 throws NotStrictlyPositiveException
```

> Parameters:
>   rowDimension - Number of rows in the new matrix.
>   columnDimension - Number of columns in the new matrix.

and

> NotStrictlyPositiveException - if the row or column dimension is not positive.

You can find more about it

[here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/Array2DRowRealMatrix.html).

Comment: With what values will it get initalised ??

Answer (score 0):

As it is based on double[][], almost certainly full of 0.0 if using that constructor